# No resource identifier found for attribute 'configchanges' in package 'android'

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-manifest

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/a512" android:label="KMI" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:name="md5ce51fed3f5ce2f508bfc10049c6540f6.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

the problem seems to be with configchanges part here. Is there any way to fix it? I did try to remove it, but it just comes back and the same error comes up.

```
 [Activity(Label = "KMI", Icon = "@drawable/a512", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
```

Comment: Did you still face the problem when adding the attribute in Activity class?

Comment: the attribute was always there, it turns out I had an extra something added in one of the manifiest file. I think that happened whilst integrating google ads. Solved now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin, it is better that you provide these in the Activity Attribute of your Activity class file. Assume that you would like to do this in your `MainActivity` file. Then what you can do is something like below:

```
 [Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/MyTheme",  ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
 public class MainActivity : global:: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

Comment: added that to the question.